# how to correctly append xml child elements in php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to iterate over an array of movie names and am struggling as shown below. I've included the actual output vs expected output.  thanks!

```
$root = new SimpleXMLElement('<movies/>');
$movies = ['foo', 'bar'];
foreach($movies as $movie_name){
    $movie_el = buildMovieTag($movie_name);
    $root->addChild($movie_el->asXML());
}


function buildMovieTag($name){
    $movie_tag = new SimpleXMLElement('<movie/>');
    $movie_tag->addChild('name', $name);
    return $movie_tag;
}
```

I'm expecting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies>
<movie><name>foo</name></movie>
<movie><name>bar</name></movie>
</movies>
```

but am getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies><<?xml version="1.0"?>  // extra xml tag
<movie><name>foo</name></movie>
/><<?xml version="1.0"?> // extra xml tag
<movie><name>bar</name></movie>
/></movies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new SimpleXMLElement` then `asXML()` is the issue.

addChild is enough to make the element then its return value is the node, then subsequent addChild's on the node make the children.

```
<?php
$root = new SimpleXMLElement('<movies/>');
$movies = ['foo', 'bar'];
foreach($movies as $movie_name) {
    $movie = $root->addChild('movie');
    buildMovieTag($movie, $movie_name);
}

function buildMovieTag($node, $name) {
    $node->addChild('name', $name);
}

echo $root->saveXML();
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies><movie><name>foo</name></movie><movie><name>bar</name></movie></movies>
```

---

Edit: if your data is more extensive, structure it so its standard key/value array then loop over the items. The actual issue to the original question is noted on the first line of the answer.

```
<?php
$root = new SimpleXMLElement('<movies/>');
$movies = [
    ['name'=>'foo', 'released' => '2020-12-01 00:00:00', 'plot' => 'foo is a foofoo'],
    ['name'=>'bar', 'released' => '2020-12-02 00:00:00', 'plot' => 'bar is a barbar'],
];
foreach ($movies as $movie) {
    buildMovieTag($root->addChild('movie'), $movie);
}

function buildMovieTag($node, $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
        // just year from datetime string
        if ($key === 'released') $item = date_create($item)->format('Y');
    
        $node->addChild($key, $item);
    }
}

echo $root->saveXML();
```

Result (manual formatted)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies>
    <movie>
        <name>foo</name>
        <released>2020</released>
        <plot>foo is a foofoo</plot>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <name>bar</name>
        <released>2020</released>
        <plot>bar is a barbar</plot>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

Comment: thanks. I suppose I might have constrained my example a bit too much. I was hoping that I'd be able to have `buildMovieTag` also add other child elements like so: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movies><movie><name>foo</name><released>2020</released><plot>foo</plot></movie><movie><name>bar</name><released>2019</released><plot>bar</plot></movie></movies>`

Comment: see edit, or if you only have the name, then inside buildMovieTag you would need pull the data